# ValueError: X has 201 features per sample; expecting 1

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

i am tring to make predictions based on 2 df columns with `sgd.predict_proba`
when i am passing 2 args to `predict_proba` i got an value error `ValueError: X has 201 features per sample; expecting 1`

i tried

`data['predicted'] = sgd.predict_proba(np.hstak((data['vector'].tolist(), data[['cosine_similarity']].values)))[:, 1]`

data['cosine_similarity'] column looks like a nested list -> `[[x float values],[x float values]]`
data['vector'] looks like a 2d array -> `\[\[x float values\]\]`

Answer (score 0):

Is your sgd object a [sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn-linear-model-sgdclassifier) ?

If so, `predict_proba` only takes a single argument : the feature matrix, which is expected to have shape `(n_samples, n_features)`. What have you used to train your model ? Is `data` a `pandas.DataFrame` ? If so, you can extract its underlying training / prediction data as a `numpy.ndarray` using the `value` attribute of your `DataFrame`.

Also, do you really want to get probability estimates ? Beware that not all classifiers are calibrated. `sklearn` classifiers provide a `predict` method which only returns the predicted class though.